# When do I use center of mass versus conservation of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

For example, if you are given your velocity in a problem where you are standing on a block slab which is on top of ice, you would use conservation of momentum.
On the other hand, a question about a person standing on a floating barge walking to one end would use center of mass. I tried using conservation of momentum for the barge problem, but it doesn't give the same answer.
When do I use which and why?

Comment: @BillN gives a good answer below.  If you are still having trouble getting the correct answer for the barge question, feel free to show your work on it here to try to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are conservation of momentum approaches. In the center of mass frame the total momentum is zero, and if there are no outside forces, it stays zero.

Sometimes it's very easy to stay in the reference frame in which a problem is given, and other times a solution is easier if you switch to CoM reference.  Both are equally valid techniques.  Whic one to use often depends on your disposition.

I recommend that students beginning to learn physics try solving these types of problems in both CoM and non-CoM reference frames.  It's great algebraic and conceptual exercise.

Comment: But I tried to solve the barge problem using conservation of momentum, and the answers were not the same.

Comment: You will have to sort through the details on your own. In fact, if you figure out how to do it both ways, you will have learned a great deal.  You *must* get the same answer.